# Can't load to Connect account - clang: error: no such file or directory

Tags: ios, xcode, plugins, assets, archive

I am having a nightmare over something that should be really simple. I have a xcode workspace file that I am trying to upload to my connect account with apple. 
All I should need to do is change developer info and upload but it fails to archive with the following error:

: '/Users/Dan_Thomas/Downloads/Assets/Plugins/iOS/GADUNativeCustomTemplateAd.m'
clang: error: no input files

How do I fix this

Thanks in advance - Going crazy here!

Comment: GADUNativeCustomTemplateAd.m file is inside your project folder or your system **Download** directory?   Right click on the file and "Show in Finder" will help you to identify the location.

Comment: Ok so how do I change it?

Comment: Is that inside your project or not?